# Chat clients in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

So I've spent many years (on and off) reading about sockets and stuff in .NET and have compiled many, many sample code and so-called *working examples* of chat clients - and not a single one of them have worked.

Most of the time I can't even get it to work on localhost. And most of the time in the past people have said "your code looks fine, it should be working", which usually leads to them saying something about my ISP might be blocking some port or whatever.

But commercial chat clients (MSN, Skype, etc) work. So there has to be a way.

Now I've finally got my own little chat client working just fine, and the problem is that someone always needs to supply an IP address in order to establish a connection and begin the chat.

Now I'm wondering, how do other chat clients know which IP to connect to?

1. Do all the clients just connect to some web service, which just feeds back whatever messages it has received?
2. Or do these chat clients store your IP address when you Sign Up and Sign In to the service via the chat client, and if you have contacts saved, it will look up their IP address(es) to know where to send your message to?

I could go on reading about this but I'd really like a straight-forward answer, if it's possible because there are so many ways to make a chat client, I feel that there could be many correct answers.

So, how do the big guys do it? How do *they* know where to send a message to? (do they store IP's for later use?)

Answer (score 2):

I think that 'the big guys' are all using a client-server architecture, so that every client has to 'sign-in' to a server before starting chatting, and by doing this its registers itself in there.
Then, the server routes the chatting to arrive from one client to the other. I doubt if it creates a direct socket connection between two clients (at least in MSN, Google Hangouts and Skype).

Answer (score 1):

Is your chat client a Peer 2 Peer model?  In other words, do the clients connect directly to each other?  If so, then they will need to know the IP/hostname of the other peers, or they will need to provide a way to publish their connection info.  Going with that second method, you are close to establishing a client-server model.  In this case, the server keeps track of the client sessions and routes the messages.

The "big guys" use a client-server model, so it's close to option #1 in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, nr.1. A service *must* use some variant of this, as an IP can change, etc. Basically, you need to find the IP somewhere each time.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, clients don't connect directly, instead, they use a server who is in charge of communicating them, among other things. I think that documentation about MSN protocol will be of some help for you.

http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/

Answer (score 1):

For IRC or telnet-based chat-clients, yes, the clients will connect to a central server that relays messages back and forth based on channels, PMs, etc., whatever features the central chat server supports. An easy way to track down some sample code would be to look for old DIKU mud code or something similar. The core ideas are the same as a chat server, except that a MUD server imposes additional gameplay logic.

For a peer-to-peer system, clients still will typically connect to a central service to initiate a "match-making" session, and then connect to one another directly (abandoning their central service connections once they're done shaking hands, presumably). There are some additional details that complicate this, such as NAT tunneling, etc. -- your router may defeat the match-making by preventing your friend's inbound connection to you from working, in other words. Your ISP may also defeat it, depending on what "services" it allows you to provide.

The first solution is often more widely compatible for a variety of users because of the NAT/firewall issues described above, but it requires more service infrastructure to support.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a DNS provider. When you want to connect to those "big guys" they have their host names in a DNS. For example, when you want to connect to the NASA you type in www.nasa.org, the PC will search in the local etc/hosts file for that name if it is not there it will send a UDP packet to the DNS specified in the network configuration asking for the IP of that host.

If you want to create your host name:

You need to create your own domain (i.e. mydomain.net) 35-40$ per year.

Create your DNS host, server.mydomain.com, server2.mydomain.net, etc

Have your router or PC update the DNS provider with the public IP of the hosts every time 
  the IP changes. Some ISP can give you a static IP (more expensive) but most of the time they give  you a dynamic IP, every time the router is reset the public IP will change, sometimes they assign you the same IP.

That's how those big guys do, more o less, I suppose they have their own DNS servers etc. But that’s the idea.

Take a look at www.dyndns.org